# How do I locate uncorrupted versions of corrupted files after running sfc /scannow

Tags: windows-8, dism, sfc

I had some corrupted system files. I have run sfc /scannow several times, and Dism ... RestoreHealth (followed by sfc /scannow again). This has fixed nearly everything, but I am left with the following two corrupted files:

```
"2015-07-21 13:14:46, Info                  CSI    0000047e [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"utc.app.json" of Microsoft-Windows-Unified-Telemetry-Client, Version = 6.3.9600.17842, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch

2015-07-21 13:14:46, Info                  CSI    00000480 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:66{33}]"telemetry.ASM-WindowsDefault.json" of Microsoft-Windows-Unified-Telemetry-Client, Version = 6.3.9600.17842, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch

2015-07-21 13:14:48, Info                  CSI    00000484 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:154{77}]"Package_1_for_KB3068708~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.0.3068708-1_neutral_GDR"
```

They appear several times in the CBS log file for the last instance of scf /scannow. As far as I am aware, I have no AMD hardware in the system, so can I safely ignore this? If not, how can I repair the files? I note that the relevant update (KB3068708) is listed as optional, so would uninstalling it solve the problem?

I am running Windows 8.1 Pro and I have the (Windows 8) installation DVD.

Comment: Your title doesn't make sense, it refers to "uncorrupted files"?

Comment: The files are not connected to AMD hardware, all 64-bit references is designated as AMD64, because AMD designed the 64-bit extension for x86.  You need to find a new source for KB3068708, you can easily enough extract that from a working system, if you want.  A corrupt .json file can be safely ignored, or again extract, from a known working system.

Comment: Probably the title was badly constructed. I wanted to ask how to locate the uncorrupted versions of the files, but this is now redundant following the answer below.

Comment: @PatrickC - You should still fix the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those files show as corrupted for anyone who installed the KB3068708 update -
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3068708

> This update contains the following two manifests that are occasionally
>   updated by the Diagnostic Tracking Service:
>
> - telemetry.ASM-WindowsDefault.json
> - utc.app.json
>
> The two files are marked as static files in the update. When an advanced user runs the System File Checker Tool (sfc.exe), the files are unintentionally
>   flagged as corrupted. There is no impact or actual corruption on a
>   device that is running this update, and this issue will be fixed in a
>   later service update

Microsoft are aware of the issue and state it will be fixed at a later date.

Optionally, you can uninstall the update to resolve the issue but this isn't necessary. Having SFC show the two files as corrupt doesn't cause any issues.

Comment: Thank you, you have set my mind at rest and I can get back to work at last.

Comment: Glad I did not install that one!